# Are all folders named "core" core dumps?

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to free up space by deleting core dumps. I ran the command `find / -xdev -name core -ls -o  -path "/lib*" -prune` and I got a list of folders named core.

Is it safe to delete all the files that show up? Here are some of the files.

```
4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Sep  6  2015 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core
4 drwxr-xr-x  14 root     root         4096 Mar  2  2015 /root/tmp/npm-4043-d0IHHSfz/1425292093565-0.44138856674544513/package/src/core
4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Mar 18  2015 /root/.npm/bower/1.3.12/package/test/core
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folders named `core` usually don't contain core dumps but core components of some software package. Never delete them unless you are really sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

No, this looks pretty unsafe to delete.

Answer (score 0):

No, as others pointed out, you do not want to remove *directories* named `core`. Files, however, are probably safe. So, change your command to:

```
find / -type f -xdev -name core -ls -o  -path "/lib*" -prune
```

Now, I don't quite understand why you would use that command. It will look for files (or directories, in your original) named `core` and list them (`-ls`) and, if the listing fails, it will look for paths beginnign with `/lib`. That's what `-ls -o  -path` means.

I think what you wanted to do is find all files/dirs named `core` OR whose path begins with `/lib`. If so, and again limiting to files only, you want:

```
find / -xdev -type f \( -name core -o -path "/lib*" \) -ls
```